# SSL Intermediate CA used to create and sign client certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl

So I have my self-signed root CA, which I used to create an intermediate CA, both of which look good and work fine.  While trying to create and sign a client certificate I receive an error opening the private key used, but when I check things the file is there as it should be.  Here are the steps that I took with this.

```sh
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out intermediate/private/controllers-ecc.key.pem 2048

chmod 400 intermediate/private/controllers-ecc.key.pem

openssl req -config intermediate/ssl_ca_devices.cnf \
    -key intermediate/private/controllers-ecc.key.pem -new -sha256 \
    -out intermediate/csr/controllers-ecc.csr.pem

openssl ca -config ./intermediate/ssl_ca_devices.cnf \
      -extensions server_cert -days 375 -notext -md sha256 \
      -in ./intermediate/csr/controllers-ecc.csr.pem \
      -out ./intermediate/certs/controllers-ecc.cert.pem
```

That last command will spit out the following:

```sh
Using configuration from ./intermediate/ssl_ca_devices.cnf
Error opening CA private key ~/Desktop/ca/intermediate/private/ca-devices-ecc.key.pem
140602185837312:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:406:fopen('~/Desktop/ca/intermediate/private/ca-devices-ecc.key.pem','r')
140602185837312:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:408:
unable to load CA private key
```

I can literally copy the string above and open the file that it errors on opening:

```sh
cat ~/Desktop/ca/intermediate/private/ca-devices-ecc.key.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,CA927018408CCDD198827262EB52238A
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So my question is whether this file is somehow mis-formatted or invalid in some way that would cause this error?  Or perhaps I'm calling the file incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ... fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:406:fopen('~/Desktop/ca/intermediate/private/ca-devices-ecc.key.pem','r')
> ```

The path `~/...` is not the real filename but the `~` gets expanded by the shell to the users home directory. If used outside the shell (like in a configuration file) this shortcut is usually not supported, i.e. you have to specify the actual path, like `/home/whoever/...`. To get the full path you could use `echo` or similar, like

```
$ echo ~/tmp
/home/whoever/tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and yes I'm aware that it's shortcut, however the bash shell will automatically translate the path to /home/<user>, which I can see being used.  All of these steps however were executed in the same user session, but to be certain I did also attempt using the full path name, but had the same end result.  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the format of the file, rather than the file actually not being there.

Comment: @user1599237: The error message from OpenSSL clearly shows that the path is not translated by the shell. It looks more that you have this path inside the file `./intermediate/ssl_ca_devices.cnf`  which is not interpreted by the shell. *"... bash shell  ... which I can see being used."* - there is only one place where you show that you use the path in the shell (i.e. `cat ~/...`) and it works in this place.